# Is there a correction due to metric tensor effects in the calculus of nuclear cross-sections?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, curvature, scattering-cross-section, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Gravitation force is negligible at the nucleus scale, but since cross-sections are essentially surfaces of interaction one should expect large effects due to the metric tensor being affected by masses. Has the effect ever been calculated in astrophysics?

Answer (score 1):

A nucleus has a characteristic size of about $10^{-15}\ {\rm m}$. Gravitational effects are measured in terms of curvature $\sim L^{-2}$, where $L$ is the length scale over which the geometry is changing. Gravity will be important for nuclear scattering in vacuum if the curvature length scale is smaller than or comparable to nuclear size $L \lesssim 10^{-15}\ {\rm m}$.

Near the horizon of a non-spinning black hole (which is as close as you can get without falling in), the curvature length scale is approximately the Schwarzschild radius. The curvature length scale is larger if you are further away or dealing with a less dense object than a black hole with the same mass. Furthermore, heavier black holes have larger Schwarzschild radius. So we can ask, what is the maximum mass of a black hole so that the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$ satisfies $r_s \lesssim 10^{-15}\ {\rm m}$.

Plugging in numbers,
\begin{equation}
M \lesssim \frac{(10^{-15}\ {\rm m})c^2}{2G} = 6.7 \times 10^{11}\ {\rm kg} = 3 \times 10^{-19} M_\odot
\end{equation}
where $M_\odot$ is the mass of the sun. Needless to say, this is an absolutely tiny black hole on astrophysical scales, so the gravity of astrophysical black holes or other bodies will not have any effect on nuclear scattering processes in vacuum.

Having said that, gravity *does* have a big influence on nuclear matter in neutron stars. The reason is that gravitational collapse leads to an enormous *pressure* and *density* in neutron stars, at low temperature (compared to the Fermi temperature). The *environment* in a neutron star does have a big influence on how neutrons and other nuclear matter behaves; for example neutrons cannot decay because of the Pauli exclusion principle.